# Не правильно отображается бургер меню

Tags: html, css, css3

Кнопка меню отображается криво, ниже приложил код!

```css
.menu__link {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 36px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

span,
span::before,
span::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 26px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #248cec;
}

span::before,
span::after {
  content: '';
}

span::before {
  transform: translateY(-7px);
}

span::after {
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<a class="menu__link" href="#">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сам разобрался!
Убрал left: 50% и отцентрировал свойством justify-content: center